# How do I access a variable in a constructor from a method in C#

Tags: c#, class, methods, constructor, properties

I would like to access a variable (an array) declared inside a constructor from a method. How would I achieve that?  In the below example, I would like to use the variable 'a'.

```
public example(int x)    
{  
    int[] a = new int[x];
}  

public void method()  
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; ++i)
    {
        // the usage of `a`
    }
}
```

Comment: You could create a field `int[] a`

Comment: Declare 'a' as a class variable or static class variable

Comment: You can't. It doesn't work like that. You need to move that outside the constructor.

Comment: You'll have to define a [field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields) for holding it. What you've done here is declared a local variable. Once the function (in this case the constructor) is finished the variable is no longer accessible.

Comment: @OfirWinegarten Strictly speaking it's a bit more complicated as it's still possible to access this variable's data using some 'hacks' like reading directly from pointer in memory. It's sufficient to say that this variable will be collected by garbage collector and can't be accessed from outer scope

Answer (score 2):

I would create a private field for `a` like:

```
private readonly int[] _a;

public Example(int x)
{
   _a = new int[x];
}


public void method()
{
   for(int i = 0; i < _a.Length; ++i)
   // Rest of your code
}
```

please note that if you would like to modify `_a` after its construction, you have to remove `readonly`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I will try your method, I am still new to programming so I will have to find out what _ means first.

Comment: @Neeblet `_` has no meaning but just a coding style. A really big community of developers have been naming `private` members with `_` prefix. Its just a habit. You can name your class members anyway you want in order to achieve the goal in your question.

Comment: `_` doesn't mean anything, it's considered much the same as a letter. It's a common convention in C# to name private fields beginning with `_` as a convenient way of making sure they never clash with the name of a local variable, but it doesn't have any actual meaning in the language.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, the scope of variable 'a' is only until the end of constructor as you declared it inside the constructor. If you want to use the variable 'a' outside the constructor, you should declare it outside the constructor but within the scope of the class.

```
class example
{
   private int[] a;
   public example(int x)    
   {  
      a = new int[x];
   }  

   public void method()  
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; ++i)
      {
         // the usage of `a`
      }
   }
}
```

It is suggested to declare this variable as a private member so that it cannot be assigned outside the class directly.

Answer (score 0):

Method to achieve is declare it as property of that class. In constructor you should initialize private properties. So the code would look like this:

```
    private int[] _a {get; set;}
    public example(int x)
    {
        int[] a = new int[x];
        _a = a;
    }

    public void method()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < a; ++i)
```